# intersection of the unit cube and a hyperplane containing the main diagonal

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Let $A$ be a linear $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$ $m < n$, containing the point $(1,1,\ldots,1) \in \mathbf{R}^n$,
and consider the intersection of $A$ and the unit cube $\Delta_n$ (centered at the origin).

I'm interested in the behavior of $\Delta_n \cap A$.
Can this body only be a parallelotope, or are there counter-examples?

Comment: Can you state the definition of a parallelotope?

Comment: ...and clarify whether the "unit cube $\Delta_n$" is has side-length $1$
or radius $1$?  (In the former case, $\Delta_n = [-1/2, +1/2]^n$ and
the point $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is in the exterior; while in the latter,
$\Delta_n = [-1, +1]^n$ and you're asking about the the intersection
with a subspace that contains one of the vertices.)

Answer (score 8):

Counterexample: for $(m,n)=(3,4)$ we can get a regular octahedron as 
the intersection of the tesseract $\Delta_4$ with the hyperplane
$x_1+x_2 = x_3+x_4$.  [It's easier to think of the equivalent
but more symmetrical $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$, where the pairs of opposite 
vertices are $\pm(1,1,-1,-1)$, $\pm(1,-1,1,-1)$, and $\pm(1,-1,-1,1)$
(or half of those vectors if "$\Delta_4$" is meant to have
*side-length* $1$ rather than $\ell^\infty$-*radius* $1$).]